# UPDARAfter I moved my dsl modem upstairs it slowed down considerably

Tags: networking, router, internet-connection, adsl, broadband

I moved my main desktop computer up one floor which unfortunately does not have a WIFI connection and still requires an Ethernet cable. For some reason I am not able to connect my DSL modem to my phone outlets on the upper floor (the modem only works with the one outlet downstairs). I opted to run a longer phone cable up to my router. Now the connection drops more frequently and the speed is horrendous.

I am now wondering if having the cable run up in this manner is causing performance problems.

How can I get the modem to work with the other phone outlets?

---

**UPDATE (answers to Qs below):**

1. All other outlets can function as phone lines and are working.
2. When I move the operation downstairs again I get full speed.
3. There is about 20 feet of phone cable running up.
4. The DSL filter was removed.

Comment: Do your other phone outlets work as phone lines?

Comment: if you move it back downstairs, does it work correctly again?

Comment: About how much extra wire is the signal now running through? Distance does matter and can degrade signal quality thereby decreasing the speed a modem syncs at. You can always call your ISP and ask them to tell you what rate the modem synced at and test the signal to noise ratio on the circuit. They should also be able to run a line test (plugged/unplugged test) to get the distance on the line between the DSLAM and modem and tell you if you passed a boundary by extending the circuit.

Comment: Did you remove the DSL filter on the jack upstairs before connecting the modem? That will keep it from working.

Comment: What kind of "phone cable" are you using to extend the connection upstairs?  Ordinary phone extension cables are cheap, not *twisted pair* cable, and are only good for voice bandwidth (< 4 KHz).  **You need to use twisted pair cable, aka UTP.**  The problem is finding UTP with RJ11 instead of RJ45 plugs.

Comment: If your ADSL modem works on only one phone outlet, then you should open up that wall plate, and compare the color wire connections to a wall plate upstairs. The connections might be different if the DSL was wired to a dedicated wire pair in your house, especially if you have a whole-house DSL filter or splitter. A telco technician offered to route the DSL to a dedicated wire pair (separate from the pair used for voice) when I has having issues.

Comment: @CharlieRB, that is not necessarily true, that is only necessary on a small percentage of DSL lines, ie lineshare lines, not dry loops.

Comment: @Sawdust, you can use any phone line to extend a phone circuit, DSL does not require twisted pair until AFTER it hits the modem and becomes ethernet. Before that, it is ATM and runs over straight pair the entire route to the home. It will, however, work just fine over twisted pair if you happen to run that.

Comment: @MaQleod - Maybe I went overboard, but documentation & accessories I've received with ADSL modems from the telco contradict your statements.  Modem docs explicitly warn not to use flat phone extension cable, and to use the supplied cable for the connection between the wall plate and the modem.

Comment: @sawdust, I wired up telco mainframes and DSLAMS and a bunch of prems for five years and did end user support and testing for last mile connections (DSLAM to modem) for 2. I'm certain that any two wire copper cable will work fine for an ATM signal. All the copper between the MDF and DSLAM is straight pair (25 pair bundle) and all the copper that goes out to the street is the same type (many bundles of 25 pairs, all straight wire) and these go all the way to the NID on the house. From there, internal wiring is usually cat3, which is twisted pair, but doesn't need to be, it is just cheaper.

Comment: @sawdust, in general, the cat3 twisted pair is used internally and doesn't typically have plugs, it is wired to jacks, though it is perfectly fine to use externally as well. The flat pair cable is generally used externally and usually comes with plugs attached. The only important thing is that the distance between the DSLAM and the modem remains within the range required for the current connection speed.

Comment: @Jason, what is the rated speed of the connection? is this lineshare or a dry loop?